# fetch data from two databases in one installation of cake php

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I had two database in my local phpmyadmin. I want to fetch and display data from the tables of both databases using the cake php.
I had lot of search in google but nothing got exact what i want so please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html) you will need to:

1) Define the two database connections inside Config/databases.php:

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
  function __construct() {
    $this->default = array (
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'hostname',
        'login' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'database_name_one',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8'
    );
    $this->second = array (
        'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'hostname',
        'login' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'database_name_two',
        'prefix' => '',
        'encoding' => 'utf8'
    );
  }
}
```

In the models that use a table in the 'second" database, define:

```
public $useDbConfig = 'second';
```

CakePHP will take care of opening the connection as needed.